# Converting UTM to Lat Long with pythons utm

Tags: python, coordinate-system, utm

From another answer on this stackexchange I found the utm pypi package, which seems awesome.
I seem to however get a wrong result for:

```
utm.to_latlon(246000, 9860000, 37, 'S')
```

It is possible though that I may just not understand it well enough (I just learned about utm and the geospatial data)

the output is:

```
(88.51038878697912, -189.68359627626393)
```

But I am expecting:

```
-1.265610402092456, 36.7174203637869
```

which I got from this website and is what I am expecting:
http://rcn.montana.edu/Resources/Converter.aspx

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of times the UTM grid system is simplified to north (N) and south (S) hemispheres. But the grid zones on the latitude axis are actually most of the letters of the alphabet. See the wikipedia image [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#/media/File:Universal_Transverse_Mercator_zones.svg). The zone 37 S is actually in north Africa, in the *northern* hemisphere.

Your location is in grid zone 'M' so the `utm` call would be:

```
utm.to_latlon(246000, 9860000, 37, 'M')
(-1.265610382990383, 36.71742036367453)
```

You can also declare the hemisphere by using the `northern` argument which, admittedly, is not well documented.

```
utm.to_latlon(246000, 9860000, 37, northern=False)
(-1.265610382990383, 36.71742036367453)
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! I was going through this and I thought it can't be a bug since it's used here so wildly